# WebView outlet mysteriously not available in XIB

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, webkit, webview

Just trying to make a simple WebView Mac app.

I've imported WebKit.h, declared a WebView @property, and @synthesized it in the .m, but when I go into IB and the connections tab, my outlet, say MyWebView, is not listed.

.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
     NSWindow *window;
     IBOutlet WebView *MyView;
 }
 @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet WebView *MyView;
@end
```

.m

```
 @synthesize MyView;
```

Latest version of Xcode. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you checking for the outlet correctly? Walk us through it (or a screenshot might be nice)

Comment: What do you mean by checking for the outlet? I'm looking at my XIB file in IB, under the Connections Inspector tab > Outlets...

Comment: Okay, I figured it out ... I was looking in the connections inspector for the *WebView*, not the AppDelegate. Duh. BUT, when launched, it's still blank (even though now the WebView is connected to the IBOutlet) ... using the same code in applicationDidFinishLaunching: as I posted previously ... does that code look sound? Why am I still getting a blank white screen when I run the app?

Comment: Actually, I guess I didn't post it previously ... `- (void)awakeFromNib {
 NSString *resourcesPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
 NSString *htmlPath = [resourcesPath stringByAppendingString:@"/htdocs/index.html"];
 [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath]]];
}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that is defined like:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
```

If you haven't added IBOutlet, IB won't show it as such.

Comment: .h   #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
     #import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

    @ interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject         <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet WebView *MyView;
}

@ property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@ property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet WebView *MyView;

@ end
.m   @synthesize MyView; ... this is why I banging my head on the wall. That should do it, no? And yet, not showing up in my outlets i IB...

Comment: Outlets don't go in the Application Delegate.  They go in a View Controller class most often and that VC is associated with an IB nib.  Are you using storyboards or Nib files?

Comment: My answer assumed iOS.  I don't know how much the rule change as far as putting outlets in the AppDelegate.  I wouldn't think that would be good on either platform, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: This is the tutorial I was going off of: http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-embed-html5-into-a-native-mac-osx-app/

Comment: Perhaps someone could just point me to another tutorial for this task? All I'm doing is making an app with a WebView that loads a URL from wherever ... that's it. Yet, there seems to be a dearth of resouces on how to do this...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted -- I copied it into a project and the outlet did show up in IB. Putting outlets in the app delegate is fine also (the default template for a cocoa project puts the outlet for the main window in the app delegate). I can't explain why it's not working for you, unless there's something else you did in the project setup that you haven't mentioned.  What do you mean by the "connections tab"?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code you posted a little more carefully, I think the problem has to do with the name of your app delegate -- how (and why?) did you change it from the default AppDelegate? Is the blue cube in IB named AppDelegate or is it named MyAppDelegate?  If it's the former, that's your problem -- change its class to MyAppDelegate in the Identity Inspector in IB.

Comment: I'm a little confused ... you don't see how or why it's been changed *from* the default AppDelegate, but then you suggest I change it to something other than that?

Comment: What rdelmar is saying is that the AppDelegate's class name should never be changed.  This is something that the user (you) would have done.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? In Xcode 4, the template always names it AppDelegate.  In any case, the important fact is that, the name of the file is the same as the name of the blue cube in IB.  Does the default outlet for the window show up?

Answer (score 0):

See my comments on my original question. Error on my part.